# What is the correct way to install express.js with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, npm

I am trying to setup a new project using express.js with typescript enabled.

Is it good enough to just install @types/express, just like below

```
npm install @types/express
```

or I need to also install

```
npm install express
```

Comment: you need to install both. one for typings of express and other is the core package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need both. One is the actual Express package:

```
nom install express
```

The other one is for TypeScript:

```
npm install @types/express
```